# Find all in model where date is today

Tags: cakephp

I was wondering if someone could show a simple example of how to use CakePHP's find feature, to solve the problem of finding all where a date field is equal to some time today, or within the range of 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 would be another way of saying it.

I have this so far:

```
$begin = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
$end = date("Y-m-d 23:59:00");

$this->set('data', $this->Posts->find(array('all', 'conditions' =>
             array('date_created>=' => $begin, 'date_created <=' => $end));
```

But doesn't work.

I've read through the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with CakePHP but based on your link I suppose you should have to do like this {name of model}.date_created

Comment: I would try this: $this->Posts->find('all', array('conditions' => array('{Model}.date_created>=' => $begin, '{Model}.date_created <=' => $end)));

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! And when it comes to queries it's also useful to know what DBMS/storage-engine you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'DATE(Post.date_created)' => date('Y-m-d')
    )
));
//or
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.date_created >=' => $begin,
        'Post.date_created <=' => $end
    )
));
```

Cake has "standard" fields for [created/modified](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified). Try to use them.

Comment: Thank you, the first option you showed is great. Cakephp seems to be all about taking advantage of the built-in conventions/"standards", and if you don't use them, you can have problems.

Answer (score 0):

## If you are using mysql-

```
$this->Post->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Post.date_created >= CURRENT_DATE()'
    )
));
```

Comment: the one who gives minus vote, I will very happy if you plz explain the reason?? I might learn something.......

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer - except if there are any future-dated records they would be returned. - Perhaps clarify the sql as executed and why/how it works (you're relying implicitly on YYYY-MM-DD XX:XX being > YYYY-MM-DD - which may not be obvious to readers). +1.